# Unhiding all divs of multi-step form if not valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a multistep form with error validation, currently if there is an error the form jumps back to the first div rather than where the actual error is.

I would like to each step automatically expanded and displayed if there an error is triggered.

There are six steps in total all with the same class name of 'step'. The 'next' button cycles through step until the final step when it is swapped for a submit button.

Error validation is done on submit not next.

UPDATED: To shorten code and clean up example.

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var current = 1;

    widget      = $(".step");
    btnnext     = $(".next");
    btnback     = $(".back"); 
    btnsubmit   = $(".submit");

    // Init buttons and UI
    widget.not(':eq(0)').hide();
    hideButtons(current);
    setProgress(current);

    // Next button click action
    btnnext.click(function(){
        if(current < widget.length){
            // Check validation
            if($(".form").valid()){
                widget.show();
                widget.not(':eq('+(current++)+')').hide();
                setProgress(current);
            }
        }
        hideButtons(current);
    })

    // Back button click action
    btnback.click(function(){
        if(current > 1){
            current = current - 2;
            if(current < widget.length){
                widget.show();
                widget.not(':eq('+(current++)+')').hide();
                setProgress(current);
            }
        }
        hideButtons(current);
    })

$("form").submit(function () {
        if (!$(this).valid()) {
            $('.step').show();
        }
    }); 

});

// Hide buttons according to the current step
hideButtons = function(current){
    var limit = parseInt(widget.length); 

    $(".action").hide();

    if(current < limit) btnnext.show();
    if(current > 1) btnback.show();
    if (current == limit) { 
        btnnext.hide(); 
        btnsubmit.show();
    }
}
</script>
```

Example (cut-down) form:

```
<form name="form" method="post" class="form">
<div class="step">
<h2>Apply now</h2>

<label>Cover Amount</label>
<?= $form->CoverAmount->render_input() ?>
</div>

<div class="step">
<h2>Where do you live?</h2>

<label>Cover Amount</label>
<?= $form->CoverAmount->render_input() ?>
</div>

<div class="step">
<h2>Nearly there...</h2>

<p>...</p>
</div>

<br />

<button type="button" class="action next btn btn-primary">Next</button>
<a href="javascript: submitform()" type="button" class="action submit btn btn-success" name="stage" value="2">Apply Now</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.<?= $form->get_form_name() ?>.submit();
}
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: Simplify your example, people don't like to parse bunch of words

Comment: Your code is long, make it shorter.

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I have shortened the code.

Comment: why don't you create working demo?